# How to optimize Drools 6 KIE Session in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, elasticsearch, drools

I'm using JBoss Drools (6.3.0.CR2 version exactly) and KIE session. I get some performance problems : the use case is to send about 20 000 events in 30 seconds with a gatling script. When a rule is fired,  a correlation is made between two events and an insert query is launched by a custom manager for ElasticSearch persistence.

**The main problem is a growing latency if I use it in a real context; I mean that events are sent all day long.**

*Resume:*

1. KIE session used in a custom API Java.
2. Simple Drools rules used.
3. Upsert into ElasticSearch (1.4.4 version).

**ElasticSearch works fine, gatling script too.**

**Java code :** example of KIE session based on this [example](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/integrationtests/KieLoggersTest.java) :

```
List<String> rules = ... some rules here

KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kFileSystem = ks.newKieFileSystem();    

kFileSystem.write("src/main/resources/KBase1/rule1.drl", rules[0]);
kFileSystem.write("src/main/resources/KBase1/rule2.drl", rules[1]);
// etc ...

KieBuilder kbuilder = ks.newKieBuilder(kFileSystem);
kbuilder.buildAll();

if (kbuilder.getResults().hasMessages(org.kie.api.builder.Message.Level.ERROR)) {
    getLogger().error(kbuilder.getResults().toString());
    throw new Exception("Cannot add the rules: " + kbuilder.getResults().toString());
}

KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(ks.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
KieBaseConfiguration config = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();    
config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);

kbase = kContainer.newKieBase(config);
ksession = kContainer.newKieSession();

ruleEntryPoint = ksession.getEntryPoint("myEntryPoint");

executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ksession.fireUntilHalt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }            
    }
});
```

**Rule example :**

```
global foo.bar.ElasticSearchStorageManager manager;

rule "first event"
when e: Event(e.getType().equals("test")) from entry-point myEntryPoint then
   manager.upsert(new CustomObject(e));
   retract(e);  
end
```

**I'm new in Drools, so if you have some clues, please share! Thanks.**

Comment: The rule you have posted isn't making "a correlation ... between two events" but such rules could cause poor performance. (Normally this rule would be written `e: Event(type=="test")` but I don't think this matters much.) -- What goes on in the `upsert` method? How long does it take? -- What happens with old Event facts?

Comment: I can't post all business rules unfortunately, but others are like-minded. And I mean rules are very simple. Rules fired only with unit tests take only 5 seconds with thousand events. If Drools is used alone, it works fine. If ElasticSearch is used alone, it works fine too. I suspect a "blocking mode" between Drools thread and ElasticSearch thread.

Comment: I've tried this option : KieBaseConfiguration config = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration(); config.setOption(MultithreadEvaluationOption.YES); but it's deprecated so far.

Comment: Is `ElasticSearchStorageManager.upsert()` the only call between Drools and ElasticSearch? What does it do? As you describe it, it might very well be the reason for the degraded performance. Adding more threads to Drools won't help. If you can't post more code you might as well delete your Q.

Comment: ElasticSearchStorageManager.upsert() does this:

 BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = this.client.prepareBulk();
    for (MyItem item : items) {    
        UpdateRequestBuilder request = client.prepareUpdate(indexBuilder.apply(item.getItem()), item.getItem().getType(), item.getItem().getId());
        bulkRequest.add(request.setDoc(item.getSerializedValue()));
    }

    bulkRequest.execute();

Comment: A workaround has been found : producer / consumer pattern. Calling elasticsearch store method asynchronously does not block Drools rule execution.

Comment: Doing some external communication or i/o in RHS code is bound to slow down the rule engine. As I tried to indicate in my comments...